Clarification on Theorem 6 from Uniswap V1 Formalized Model: e_0 < e_2 and t_0 < t_2
I have been studying the formalized model of Uniswap V1 from the whitepaper and the accompanying formalized model document (left the links below in the references).
Specifically, I am focusing on Theorem 6, which states:


References:

Uniswap V1 Whitepaper
Formalized Model Document


Because this is a very specific question about a research paper, you should probably directly address this question to the paper authors, instead of a public programming forum.
